# "This modification is not allowed because the document is opened for viewing only."

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I was recently sent a form created in Microsoft Word 2013 which I am unable to edit. Any time I try to fill in any of the fields, I am shown the following message in the bottom-left corner:

> [This modification is not allowed because the document is opened for viewing only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8xlV.png)

I am able to edit blank documents or different files without issue, but this specific form will not let me edit it. The form is saved as a standard .docx file, so I'm not sure why I can't edit it.

When opened, the document displays in a strange reader view where I navigate 
between pages by clicking arrows on the left and right side of the document.

**Why is this document opened for viewing only? How can I make changes?**

Comment: You have to exit reading view. There is a button somewhere at the top, but Microsoft changed it since office 2016, so I can't look up what the button is. You can also disable the entire reading mode in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this link you need to click on **View** menu option (Upper side) and then click on **Edit document**

https://turbolaw.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204533169-Unable-to-make-any-changes-to-saved-or-blank-document-in-Word-2013-or-2016

Edit: According to the article this option is for Microsoft Word 2013 and Microsoft Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable this for all documents, go to Options and uncheck **Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view**.

[image]

[Source](https://www.nextofwindows.com/word-2013-quick-tip-how-to-disable-read-mode-as-default-view#targetText=To%20change%20the%20default%20viewing,And%20that's%20it.)

Answer (score 0):

Open doc, toolbar at top, select "VIEW" - then from drop down select "EDIT DOCUMENT"

You can switch back and forth between viewing (reading) and editing from that menu